# Datalabels fontSize and position : different results depending on browser

Tags: browser, highcharts, cross-browser

For my highchart column graph, I have 2 series and the values can be very close to each other, so overlap can happen.

On exporting, I'm reducing the fontSize property but with different results:

- [Internet Explorer](https://ibb.co/fRMMD5) : The fontSize remains the same. Ugly.
- [Firefox](https://ibb.co/m8Qyt5) : The fontSize is reduced. However, the datalabels is now not centered anymore which is ugly
- [Chrome](https://ibb.co/bt3CLk) : Perfect result ! As I would expect. FontSize reduced and centered.

Is there anything I can do or you can do (next release) ?

See the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1oqystsg/2/) :

- Open it in IE, Firefox and Chrome and export in any format (PNG in my test)

I'm changing the export like that :

```
exporting: {
        chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {      
                        allowOverlap: true,             
                        style: {
                            fontSize: 6
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the answer :).

The fontSize should be declared as "6px" and not 6.

so instead of :

```
style: {
   fontSize: 6
},
```

change it as

```
 style: {
       fontSize: "6px"
    },
```

Like that, it works as I expected on IE, FF, Chrome.